# Gluing bakelite together

Tags: everyday-chemistry, adhesion

I have an older stainless steel saucepan with what I've always called a Bakelite handle.  The pan fell, the handle broke.  If possible, I'd like to glue it.  The break is near where the handle attaches to the pan.  So, the repair would ideally bond Bakelite-to-metal stud as well as Bakelite to itself.  (pic below.  NB: the color is off: it's actually 'light black', there is no blue.)

If it matters, the pan doesn't ever go in the oven, but is used to pour boiling water.

If anyone knows what glue to use, I'd appreciate hearing.  If I should just forget about it, knowing that would help too.

[image]

Comment: [Arts and Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com) would probably be a better place to ask this question. Not much chemistry involved here.

Comment: It would be better to fabricate a new handle than to rely on a glued joint -- *consider what would happen if the handle came loose while carrying a pan filled with boiling water!*

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yeah.  On further thought, this was not a good plan.  I'm done with it.